# Testng: how to set thread-count number as launch parameter

Tags: xml, testng

I'm using testng to run tests in parallel.
Xml file contains thread-count parameter.

```
<suite name="Lalala" parallel="tests" thread-count="3" preserve-order="true">
```

But I want to set the thread-count value as parameter when launching tests.
Command line looks like

```
-ea -Dstagefile=stage -Dbrowser=chrome clean test
```

Is there some way to add thread-count to command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `-threadcount` on the command line (see *Command Line Parameters* under [Running TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)). You'll then want to omit `thread-count="3"` from your xml file so that you don't override the command line option.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, the only way to set the thread count programmatically is on `TestNG.setThreadCount()` ([Javadoc](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestNG.html#setThreadCount%28int%29)).

This would require you to write a runner class with a main method that instantiates TestNG and invokes configuration methods.  You can then accept command line args for the parameter.

While valid, it's completely redundant to just using the baked in `-threadcount` arg as @mfulton26 has stated.